# VS code color themes not working after OmniSharp icon flicks

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been using vscode for c++ since past 2 years. It all worked fine.

Today none of the color themes seems to work. All the code is selected by default and everything appears without color theme (plain white)

**What I tried :**

- when i click `Developer:restart Window`, themes work for around 10 seconds, then omnisharp icon flicks in status bar and all color themes disappear.
- Tried opening vscode in Disable all extensions mode, problem continues..
- Downgraded from 1.35.1 (May Release) to April Release.
- Restarted windows os.

Attaching Screenshot : Color Theme Before (just after Reloading Window)
[image]

Attaching screenshot : Color theme gone After Omnisharp Icon Flickered in Status bar
[image]

VScode Version : 1.34.0
OS : Windows 10

As you can see, all code is selected in some weird way and color theme isn't working.